# Properties of derived group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

If K is a normal subgroup of G then does the following equality hold:

$[G/K,G/K]=[G,G]/(K \cap[G,G]) $

If this is true then prove it and if not then give a counter example.

Comment: You should word your requests for help more politely.

Answer (score 3):

Can you show $(G/K)'= G'K/K \cong G'/(G' \cap K)$from the definition of commutators and the second isomorphism theorem? It is true!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi$ be canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G/K$

$(G/K)^{'}$ is generated by elements $[xK,yK]$ and $G^{'}$ is generated by $[x,y]$

$[xK,yK]=[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=\phi([x,y])$ $\implies$ $(G/K)^{'} \leq $ $\phi(G^{'})=G^{'}K/K$

For other inclusion just start from $[x,y]$ and find its image.